# Create Carbon date with string

Tags: laravel

I got a date:

> 19/02/2018 00:00:00

I want paginate in decrescent order, so I got to create a carbon date...

I got this to show the 10 first days:

```
$today = Carbon::today();
$lastDays = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $day = $today->subDays(1)->format('d/m/Y');
    $lastDays[] = $day;
}
```

But I want to show more, and this is to show more:

```
    $today = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s',  '19/02/2019 00:00:00'); 

$lastDays = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $day = $today->subDays(1)->format('d/m/Y');
    $lastDays[] = $day;
}
```

Don't works... returns:

> "Unexpected data found.
>   ↵Unexpected data found." On first line.

Comment: **But I want to show more** can you elaborate about this line. It's difficult to understand.

Answer (score 29):

You need to change your code like this. You have provided the wrong format to `createFromFormat` function.

```
$today = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s',  '19/02/2019 00:00:00'); 

$day = $today->subDays(1)->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 19):

With Carbon there is an method called parse that takes a string and outputs your date. If the given string isn't valid it takes the current date as a default date.

```
Carbon::parse('your date')->format('your format');
```

So in your case you should do this:

```
$today = Carbon::parse('19/02/2019 00:00:00'); 
$lastDays = array();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $day = $today->subDays(1)->format('d/m/Y');
   $lastDays[] = $day;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

```php
use \Carbon\Carbon;

$birth = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y',  '28/01/1994'); 
    
echo $birth->format('d/m/Y');
```

Comment: Be careful everyone in using this method. Be aware that when it's day 31 of July, if you try to subMonth() it will give 31/06/YYYY and this day doesn't exist, so it will return 01/07, keeping it in in July.